# Ignore Markdown characters in search using regex

Tags: regex, markdown

For search purpose I would like to use regex to find text, which is potentially "decorated" with Markdown characters.

E.g. if I have following Markdown text: `Hello **world**`, I would like it to be found using "Hello world" string. I cannot manipulate markdown text, only the search string.

Only solution I see, is to add following

```
[\[\]()*_\-#>`.|!\s]*
```

between all characters. But it results in a very ugly repetitive regex:

```
H[\[\]()*_\-#>`.|!\s]*e[\[\]()*_\-#>`.|!\s]*l[\[\]()*_\-#>`.|!\s]*l[\[\]()*_\-#>`.|!\s]*o[\[\]()*_\-#>`.|!\s]*w[\[\]()*_\-#>`.|!\s]*o[\[\]()*_\-#>`.|!\s]*r[\[\]()*_\-#>`.|!\s]*l[\[\]()*_\-#>`.|!\s]*d[\[\]()*_\-#>`.|!\s]*
```

Is there a simpler way to ignore Markdown characters in search using regex?

Comment: Not really. The simplest solution by far is to copy the markdown to a buffer and normalize it before searching. The situation is perhaps somewhat alleviated by the observation that many Markdown dialects only allow `_underscores_` or `*asterisks*` for formatting at word boundaries; so `foo_*bar` is just the string foo_*bar

Comment: Why do you include `\s` for example though? "H ello world" is not a match for "Hello world" in most contexts.

Comment: right, can be removed. But in my case I'd like "Hello  world" (double space between Hello and world) also be a match.

Comment: That's one example of something which would be useful to normalize before attempting to search. As a quick stopgap measure change spaces in your search regex to `\s+`